# rubygems.org doesn't switch to the latest gem version

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have built my first ruby app there: https://rubygems.org/gems/youtube_dlhelper. As shown in Versions the correct versions are available: 0.1.0, 0.1.1 and 0.1.2.
But it looks like rubygems lists just the oldest 0.1.0.
Maybe anyone knows why?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I have a feeling the `.alpha` suffix is confusing the algorithm that determines latest version number. Should be of the form `x.x.x-alpha(.x)`. See [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](http://semver.org) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of your gem is not showing up as the default because it does not conform to the [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) specifications. Although it may seem obvious to us as humans that `0.1.2.alpha` is greater than `0.1.0.alpha`, a quick look at the spec shows that this is the incorrect way to specify a pre-release. Here's a relevant excerpt (emphasis added by me):

> **A pre-release version MAY be denoted by appending a hyphen and a series of dot separated identifiers immediately following the patch version. Identifiers MUST comprise only ASCII alphanumerics and hyphen** [0-9A-Za-z-]. Identifiers MUST NOT be empty. Numeric identifiers MUST NOT include leading zeroes. Pre-release versions have a lower precedence than the associated normal version. A pre-release version indicates that the version is unstable and might not satisfy the intended compatibility requirements as denoted by its associated normal version. **Examples: 1.0.0-alpha, 1.0.0-alpha.1, 1.0.0-0.3.7, 1.0.0-x.7.z.92.**

I'm not exactly sure how `0.1.2.alpha` is being interpreted, but I think your best bet is to release a `0.1.3` version of your gem and yank the incorrectly versioned ones. You may even try releasing a `0.1.3-alpha`, but I'd wait until someone more knowledgable can a give a more definitive answer.

In the meantime, I'd definitely encourage you to look at the [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org) specs.

Comment: I think i had misunderstood the Variable "BUILD". I thought this stand for anything like alpha, beta and so on...